# Perform OpenLayers methods when outside images are clicked

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to set up my OpenLayers map controls (e.g ZoomIn, ZoomOut) when images elsewhere on the page are clicked. Is this an issue of formatting a control panel to display the buttons as my images (if so how should I set up the CSS to use the images), or would I be better to set up a listener on the image, that then runs the method ZoomIn on the when clicked (and if so what sort of code do I need)?

Comment: Either way would do. It actually depends on what you want to do and what images you wish to use.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I want to make clicking on one photo zoom in, and clicking on another zoom out. They are quite large photos, does that make listening for an event and running a method most appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you say

> I want to make clicking on one photo zoom in, and clicking on another
>   zoom out.

If this is the case, then your best option would be to listen to the onclick event using javascript and then call the appropriate OpenLayers functions for Zooming In and out of the map.

I have done something similar using the following code:

In HTML:

```
<div id='ZoomIn'><img class="ToolBtn" src="zin.png"title="Zoom In" onclick="ZoomIn();" ></div>
<div id='ZoomOut'><img class="ToolBtn" src="zout.png" title="Zoom Out" onclick="ZoomOut();" ></div>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function ZoomIn()
{
    map.zoomIn();
}
function ZoomOut()
{
    map.zoomOut();
}
```